# Set MediaType for the whole application

Tags: jersey-2.0

I'm currently using `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in my classes and it works fine.

Is there any way to move this to a more generic place, since my whole API will be working only with JSON and I'd like to avoid having that annotation in every single class.

Comment: You would have to do something like use a request filter and check for the Content-Type and Accept headers and send a 415 or 406, respectively, if they send something other than application/json. And also use a response filter to set the response Content-Type to application/json. Maybe not worth it. It's not that tedious to put the annotations on every class. Better than every method 

Comment: If you implemented my suggestion, I'd like to see it :-)